# How to SUM many rows into 1 row in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following is my syntax

```
with AA as 
(
  select distinct Store_Code, sum([Transactions]) as totaltrans
  from CRM_RETAIL_SUMMARY
  where Store_Code in ('L43','J62','L45','UA2','A35','949','C50','L44','Y45')
    and Trans_Hdr_Sale_Date BETWEEN '2018-12-1' AND '2018-12-31'
  group by Transactions, Store_Code
),
BB as 
( 
  select distinct[Store_Code] as storecode from CRM_RETAIL_SUMMARY
)
select AA.totaltrans, BB.storecode
from AA
inner join BB on AA.Store_Code = BB.storecode
```

and then the result shows this:

```
storecode   totaltrans
----------------------
A35          65
A35          76
A35          48
A35          62
A35          56
UA2           5
UA2           6
UA2           8
UA2          15
UA2           9
UA2          16
949          16
949          29
949          55
```

But I want to SUM each of the storecode like the following but I don't know how:

```
storecode  totaltrans
---------------------
A35         307 
UA2          59
```

Thank you for all answers

Comment: Try `sum`+`group by` ps - why is 949 missing from your expected results?

Answer (score 1):

You only need to group by `store_code`, not **store_code, transactions**. and you don't need the 2nd `cte`.

```
with AA as (
  select Store_Code, sum([Transactions]) as totaltrans
  from CRM_RETAIL_SUMMARY
  where Store_Code in ('L43','J62','L45','UA2','A35','949','C50','L44','Y45')
    and Trans_Hdr_Sale_Date BETWEEN '2018-12-1' AND '2018-12-31'
  group by Store_Code
)
select * from AA;
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you just use `group by`?

```
select BB.storecode, sum(AA.totaltrans)
from AA join
     BB
     on AA.Store_Code = BB.storecode
group by BB.storecode;
```

Of course, this goes after the CTEs.